# How do I create a stereoscopic OpenGL view on the Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

Although Apple's documentation clearly states they support stereoscopic views on the Mac with the kCGLPFAStereo and NSOpenGLPFAStereo pixel format attributes, I've been unable to get any semblance of a stereoscopic pixel format object.

I've been able to create stereoscopic output recognized by 3DTV displays by manually specifying the format as Side-by-side, but it should be recognized automatically by the hardware over HDMI.

How does one create a stereoscopic display in Cocoa or Core OpenGL with NSOpenGLPFAStereo or kCGLPFAStereo?

Comment: The fact that Apple's APIs support pixel format attributes for quad-buffer stereo does not necessarily imply that every OpenGL implementation provides such formats. Unfortunately, I don't know abouth the exact situation on OSX, so I can't answer your question. But on windows, the GPU vendors provide full support for quad-buffer GL only for their workstation products (AMD FirePro, NVIDIA Quadro), while the drivers for the consumer products are crippled in that regard. AMD is said to have partly removed that limit by allowing quad-buffer stereo for fullscreen windows (but I never tried that).